# White residue after putting bacon grease laden cookware in dishwasher

Tags: bacon, fat, dishwasher

I scrape off most of the bacon grease then put it in a dishwasher. The residue doesn't feel very greasy, it has kind of a powder feel to it. There is only residue on the cookwares, and no residue on all other plates. The cookwares are a nonstick pan and a silicone coated turner. It happened with two different brands of bacon. I'm using finish powerball tablets.

Comment: I used to cook gammon /bacon joints in a slow cooker and find the same thing (cheap or expensive DW tablets). But it came off quite easily washing up by hand (does yours?). I assumed it to be protein but never looked for a definitive answer (hence this comment, I'd like to know too).

Comment: I don't understand completely @dennis97519, is the residue on all your dishes or just some of them?

Comment: @GdD It's only on the things I used to cook bacon or used in (presumably heated) bacon fat. So the nonstick pan and the silicone turner.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, it comes off easily washing by hand washing. It's just that it's somewhat annoying. Also iirc the residue doesn't come off from rewashing in dishwasher.

Comment: @dennis97519 just the same as mine.  I often ended up putting thing through the dishwasher, then taking the residue off with a sponge and washing up liquid and rinsing cold (my hot water takes ages to run hot and I very rarely wash up by hand.  Not the best solution though.

Comment: Nonstick pan and and silicone coating are hydrophobic. They'll like to stick to bacon grease.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a dishwasher, so I do dishes by hand, but there is something I've noticed that might help--when I have something very greasy, I sometimes find it hard to get it comepletely  clean after the first washing,  washing it a second time right away doesn't work much better,   I have to wash it, let it completely dry, and then wash it again.  Perhaps putting the items with residue through a second cycle will work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying soap to a sponge and then scrubbing the dish apply liquid dish soap directly to the pan and massage gently with your hand. This should help remove remaining residue.

Answer (score 1):

I always use a liquid dish soap that is a degreaser to remove or help remove grease from any type of dish I place in the dishwasher. I rinse them some so as not to be adding a lot of extra soap to the dishwasher. And I haven't seen any problem with my dishwasher when using liquid soap. You just have to be careful how much you use. I hope this helps. Happy cleaning.